# Confusion about the App developement For windows surface Pro and Windows surface for windows rt

Tags: windows-8

I want to start an app for surface but the confusion I got is one of surface core contain windows rt and pro version contain windows 8.for pro i am fine with the development but for windows rt version.have made the project on VS 2012 for windows as in pro version(same project will work or not)or i have to make project on VS 2012 for windows phone.

Comment: This thread will be a good read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e534eb59-0365-46b8-abb0-8aacfa410542/using-same-code-for-win-rt-and-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a Windows Store (Windows 8) application you have the option to create a ARM version of that application that will run on Windows RT, so when you create the packages for your application and include ARM (or Neutral) as an option (see below), you're all set.  In most cases, you'd select Neutral, but if you are using native libraries, you'll need to create separate packages for each CPU architecture you're targeting.

[image]

I think that covers what you're asking, but let me add that Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 are two separate platforms although they share a bit of functionality and API space.  To build for each platform, it requires two separate solutions, and if you are using the "Express" versions of Visual Studio, you will need Visual Studio Express for Windows Store apps AND Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone.   The latter will require Windows 8 Pro on a 64-bit machine.

There are techniques to maximize code use between the platforms, including [portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and conditional compilation.